# Regex to find parts of a string that do not start with a hashtag

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string

```
#this is a #new day at #lf_technology and is #awes0me #Nepal #hattiban peace
```

Using `(#[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)` regex, I can extract the hashtags `#this, #new, #lf_technology, #awes0me, #Nepal, #hattiban`

I need a reg ex to extract `is a, day at, and is, peace`

Here is what I have used to test http://rubular.com/r/6i9HJUVFFa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply look for

```
/((^| )[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+)/
```

http://rubular.com/r/ypEsQY1lhM

For every character except `#` and `_` it would be:

```
/((^| )[^#_]+)/
```

http://rubular.com/r/9GhP87HFzn

As the comments below suggest, this will produce results with trailing spaces, so to use it correctly you would need to `strip` the results:

```
s.scan(/( [a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+)/).flatten.map(&:strip)
# => ["is a", "day at", "and is", "peace"]
```

Comment: @aelor You are right.. +1 to this answer. It is much simple.

Comment: @ArupRakshit yes apart from a few drawbackes like Cary mentioned, rest works fine

Comment: @Uri Agassi, that worked for the string with no special characters _such as . , /_, i also need to include the characters except for **# and _** eg that should work for **#this is a #new day at #lf_technology.,. and. is #awes0me., #Nepal/ #hattiban peace ,.,**

Comment: thanks but that also didnt match the **.,** after the *#awesome* also **/** after the **#Nepal** and **.,.** after the **#lf_technology**

Comment: Any reason to write `[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]` instead of `[\w ]`? `\w` is exactly what you have inside the character class, except for the space.

Comment: @UriAgassi the only problem is that in the above string if the first word is a **this** instead of **#this** then it fails to match this word.

Comment: @Ojash - It did not take `.,.` after `#Nepal` because they are part of a word starting with `#`. You should get your requirements straight, and then we could so this right, otherwise, it is going to get quite frustrating.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers I used what was most similar to what to OP already used

Comment: @Ojash - fixed it for the first word as well: `/((^| )[^#_]+)/`

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
/((\s[a-zA-Z]+)+)/
```

to extract `is a, day at, and is, peace`.

Ref: http://rubular.com/r/t2TWE7BXzU

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
(?<=\s)\w[^#]*(?!#)
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/sI6uE2

```
=> irb
=> s = "#this is a #new day at #lf_technology and is #awes0me #Nepal #hattiban peace"
=> s.scan(/(?<=\s)\w[^#]*(?!#)/)
=> ["is a", "day at", "and is", "peace"]
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland updated the code to fit that condition.